# Making a class Thread-Safe

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

Given:

```
public class TestSeven extends Thread {

private static int x;

public synchronized void doThings() {
    int current = x;
    current++;
    x = current;
}

public void run() {
    doThings();
  }
}
```

Which statement is true?

A. Compilation fails.

B. An exception is thrown at runtime.

C. Synchronizing the run() method would make the class thread-safe.

D. The data in variable "x" are protected from concurrent access problems.

E. Declaring the doThings() method as static would make the class thread-safe.

F. Wrapping the statements within doThings() in a synchronized(new Object()) { } block would make the class thread-safe.

isn't it enough to mark doThings() as synchronized in order to make that class Thread-safe ? i see that the correct answer is D but the Model answer of this question is E, But i don't understand why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> E. Declaring the doThings() method as static would make the class thread-safe.

That is kind of a tricky answer. The method is already synchronized, but on the instance, whereas the state is in a static field, i.e. on the class. Making it `static synchronized` is indeed the correct answer, because then it synchronizes on the class, not on a (meaningless) instance.

> D. The data in variable "x" are protected from concurrent access problems.

```
private static int x;
```

This is a static variable. It is shared by all instances of the class, so synchronizing on individual instances is not helpful, in the same way as F would not be helpful, which synchronizes on a complete throw-away dummy object.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class is used.
>
> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object
>   for which the method was invoked) is used.

This means that in the code you provided the `synchronized` keyword causes the method to acquire a lock on `this` before executing the body of the method. However, since `x` is `static` that doesn't ensure that the update to `x` will be atomic. (Another instance of the class could enter the synchronized region and do an update at the same time since they have different `this` values and thus different locks.)

However, declaring `doStuff` static will make all calls to the method acquire the same lock (the one on the `Class`) and thus would ensure mutual exclusion in the method body.

The specifications is really spelling out that:

```
class A {
    static synchronized void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is literally the same thing as

```
class A {
    static void doSomething() {
        synchronized(A.class) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly:

```
class B {
    synchronized void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

is literally the same thing as

```
class B {
    void doSomething() {
        synchronized (this) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

By way of synchronizing the doThings() method, you are holding the lock for a particular TestSeven object. However, static variables of the class does not belong to the specific instance of the object itself.  They belong to the Class object `TestSeven.class`. So, either you could go for a

```
synchronized (TestSeven.class){
    int current = x;
    current++;
    x = current;
}
```

inside your doThings() method which is acquiring the Class lock inside an instance lock which is overdoing things. So, you could mark the method as static so that you end up acquiring the lock of the Class object alone.

Answer (score 1):

Since `x` is `static` other threads could modify it at the same time `doThings` method is running. Making `doThings` `static` will stop this.

Answer (score -6):

I agree with you that the correct answer is D.
I would say that E is incorrect because if I set doThings() as static and remove the synchronized keyword, I could just start up 50 TestSeven threads and it could result in incorrect x value.

Note:
I was wrong here, I missed the point that synchronized method without static actually use the instance as the lock monitor instead of the Class itself.

Comment: E is correct because it does not say "remove the synchronized keyword". Unnecessarily tricky phrasing, but that's what you get in these exams.

Comment: D is correct, since with the given class there is no other way of changing the value of x.
If adding other method is allowed, then I would say even solution E is not correct.

Comment: @Santoso No, `D` is not correct. Imagine two instances are run on two separate threads in parallel, `testSevenA` and `testSevenB`. When `testSevenA` enters `run`, it will synchronize itself, and then start to do the work. When `testSevenB` enters `run`, it will synchronize itself, and then start to do the work. In neither case is one instance protected from the other one. If the method were made `static`, as `E` says, both instances would synchronize against `TestSeven.class`, therefore limiting `run` to being accessed by one `Thread` at a time, and therefore protecting the `static` variable.

Comment: Note: I think you might be missing part of `E`. It says to declare it as `static`, not declare it as `static` and undeclare it as `synchronized`. In other words, it should be declared `public static synchronized void doThings()`.

Comment: @pickypg You're right, I miss it. without the static keyword, the lock acquired is associated with the object itself not the object class. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You can feel free to delete this answer to salvage your points back from it.